# Partial Words Search With MySQL PHP

Tags: php, mysql, search, filter

I have a hotels database where hotel name is "Elite Super Jordan" the wildcard of mysql search with words Elite, Super, Jorder, Elite Super, Super Jordan with the following search.

```
name LIKE "%{SEARCH_KEY}%"
```

But I want to filter data with "Hotel Elite" because "Elite" exist in keyword for search in this case --> `name LIKE "%{SEARCH_KEY}%"` does not work

How can i achieve this type of search in MySQL

Comment: You should probably look in [MySQL full-text searching](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-search.html)

Answer (score 0):

One option is split the search keyword and add `OR` condition in `sql` like below.

```
SELECT * FROM youtable WHERE (name LIKE '%Hotel Elite%' OR name LIKE '%Hotel%' OR name LIKE '%Elite%' )
```

Second Option is use [MySql Full-Text Search](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-search.html)